# Installing PWA npm package fails with 404 Error in angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to build a angular PWA. I have created a new angular project and trying to do:

```js
ng add @angular/PWA
```

within the project. 
But, I am getting an Error saying:

```js
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @angular/PWA@latest
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ramya\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-07T14_47_30_848Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
Package install failed, see above.
```

I have faced similar issues earlier also with some npm packages.
I set the registry using:

```js
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: You can find a step by step guide for Angular with Pwa here: https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular In the article the different caching strategies available are also explained and the complete source code (stored on Github).

Answer (score 3):

Try

> `ng add @angular/pwa --project project-name`

Answer (score 1):

## Case sensitivity

Use lower-case letters `ng add @angular/pwa`

See [New Package Moniker rules](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/168978377570/new-package-moniker-rules). It says *You can’t create new packages with upper-case letters in the name any more*.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with NPM or with its config, it's throwing an error of E404, which means not found, the actual package name is `@angular/pwa` and not `@angular/PWA`, its case sensitive.

source: https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/pwa